# Keys enum weird behavior

Tags: c#, enums

This question https://stackoverflow.com/q/33805968/2307070 raised a few questions to the programmer that I am. So I grab VS (2013 if it matters) and added to my form this function:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Put a break point to play a bit with keyData in the Immediate Window. I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and got:

```
keyData
LButton | MButton | Back
```

Ok. So <kbd>Enter</kbd> seems to be <kbd>[Back](http://memecrunch.com/meme/I6QF/i-ll-be-back/image.jpg?w=400&c=1)</kbd>.

Here's where the fun begging:

```
keyData == Keys.Enter
true
keyData == Keys.Back
false
```

How can one explain this behavior?

Comment: Um, no - it's showing that `Enter` is a combination of `Back`, `LButton` and `MButton`. That's odd, certainly... but it does explain everything you're seeing.

Comment: (Fundamentally, it's weird that `Keys` is a flags-based enum, IMO...)

Comment: You can explain the behaviour through the use of `|` operator.  `LButton | MButton | Back != Back`  so it's no surprise that if `Keys.Enter == LButton | MButton | Back` then `Keys.Enter != Keys.Back`.  When you use `|` in this context, it can be considered the same as `+`.  Enter = [value of ]LButton + [value of]MButton + [value of]Back

Comment: @JonSkeet makes a lot of sense if you think about it hardware and windows legacy wise... look at the values: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Keys.cs,8d66d49504b4bbee

Comment: Its probably a `Flags` because of `Control`/`Shift`/`Alt`. But that could have been a second parameter/property as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works fine:

```
this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter");
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Back");
        }
    }
```